# Excel VBA / Split String Into Columns based on Character Count

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to split a String of 41 Characters like the example below:
`01288D29424001190601AJGBGR1413190528SR117`

Into different columns based on character count from left to right, my constant character count criteria to split the string is:

```
  5     6     3    6    2   4    4     6    1 1  3

01288 D29424 001 190601 AJ GBGR 1413 190528 S R 117
```

The string above will be my end result, take into consideration that every space represent a new column.

Answer (score 2):

Place your fieldwidths in **B1** through **L1** and data in **A2**.  Then in **B2** enter:

```
=LEFT(A2,B1)
```

and in **C2** enter:

```
=MID($A$2,SUM($B$1:B$1)+1,C$1)
```

and copy across:

[image]

Same logic for VBA:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    Dim s As String, arr(0 To 10) As String, i As Long
    Dim msg As String

    msg = ""
    s = "01288D29424001190601AJGBGR1413190528SR117"
    wdth = Array(5, 6, 3, 6, 2, 4, 4, 6, 1, 1, 3)
    strt = Array(1, 6, 12, 15, 21, 23, 27, 31, 37, 38, 39)

    For i = 0 To 10
        arr(i) = Mid(s, strt(i), wdth(i))
        msg = msg & vbCrLf & arr(i)
    Next i

    MsgBox msg
End Sub
```

[image]